# Can anyone tell me why I keep receiving the error "Error in mtcars$am : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"?

Tags: r, bar-chart, atomic

```
barplot(table(mtcars$am, mtcars$vs, col = c("#b9c8fd", "#c8fdb9"),
xlab = "Transmission Type",ylab = "Frequency", 
ylim = c(0,25), names.arg = c("Automatic", "Manual"), 
legend("topright", legend = c("V Shaped Engines")), pch = (19:20), 
col = c("#b9c8fd", "#c8fdb9"), abline(h=0) ))
```

I'm using the vs and am datasets within mtcars and attempting to create a barplot but this error won't function for me :( I'm a newbie so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: AFter the `table`, you forgot to close the `)` i.e. `table(mtcars$am, mtcars$vs)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in the the closing bracket after `table`.  Along with that `legend` would be a separate argument

```
barplot(table(mtcars$am, mtcars$vs), col = c("#b9c8fd", "#c8fdb9"), 
  xlab = "Transmission Type",ylab = "Frequency",  ylim = c(0,25), 
     names.arg = c("Automatic", "Manual"))
legend("topright", legend = c("V Shaped Engines"), pch = 19:20)
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for advice! I made said changes and altered the code so that it read:

```
barplot(table(vs,am), col = c("blue", "green"), 
xlab = "Transmission Type",
ylab = "Frequency",
ylim = c(0,25),
main = "Stacked Barplot...",
names.arg = c("Automatic", "Manual"),
axis.lty = 1, font.main = 4)

legend("topright", legend = c("Automatic", "Manual"), pch = 19:20,
col = c("blue", "green"))
```

and it worked!